# How can I get the address of struct member

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

This is the declaration of `_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    BYTE Reserved1[52];
    PVOID Reserved2[3];
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    PVOID Reserved3;
    ULONG HandleCount;
    BYTE Reserved4[4];
    PVOID Reserved5[11];
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER Reserved6[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

Now I have a `_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`  object.

I want to get a pointer to its `UniqueProcessId` member. How can I do that?

I tried to use `*(lpAddr->NextEntryOffset)`, but it told me I cannot apply * to unsigned long

Comment: How do you normally get the address of something?

Comment: I want to get a pointer to its NextEntryOffset but using *(lpAddr->NextEntryOffset) tells me I cannot apply * to unsigned long

Comment: @JaMiT my bad, I mistake & for * Nothing else. stupid mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistake & for *

> using *(lpAddr->NextEntryOffset) tells me I cannot apply * to unsigned long

You should use `&(lpAddr->NextEntryOffset)` since the symbol `&` is to get the address of a left-value.

Symbol `*` is just the reverse. It's applied to an **address** to get the **value** at that address.